# из for не передаётся аргумент, ошибка missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, классы, for

```
TypeError: running() missing 1 required positional argument: 'track'
```

Не понимаю, почему питону не нравится как из for я передаю аргумент в функцию, как правильно это записать? Без класса все работает

```
runners = 3
long = 100
road = [[1] * runners for i in range(long)]


class standart:
    score = []
    winner = []

    def __init__(self, LONG, RUNNERS, ROAD):
        self.long = LONG
        self.runners = RUNNERS
        self.road = ROAD

    def running(self, track):
        run = 0
        for i in range(self.long):
            run += self.road[i][track]
        return run

    for tr in range(runners):
        score.append(running(tr))

Aa = standart(long, runners, road)
print(Aa.score)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а что у вас

```
for tr in range(runners):
    score.append(running(tr))
```

делает внутри класса?

класс содержит методы и члены класса, но в вашем случае он еще и содержит голый код

Comment: Эх, какая глупая ошибка, спасибо